# Free batch image watermarking software

Tags: batch, watermark

I'm looking for a simple yet effective software to watermark a lot of photos in batch.

I have to apply a transparent png watermark image on 400 photos.

The program have to place the watermark at a custom position relative to the bottom right corner of every picture.

I would have done this in photoshop, but the scriptable action doesn't allow me to do conditionnal placing if the photo is portrait or landscape.

I'm looking for a free lightweight program.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

[XnView](http://www.xnview.com/en/xnview.html) can do this, with the batch processing feature.

You select which pictures to transform, from where to where, in which format, and which action(s) to apply to them, including adding a watermark.

And it's free!

[image]

Answer (score 7):

[Imagemagick](http://www.imagemagick.org/) can probably do what you need.

Comment: +1 Yup.  You can find several examples of how to apply different watermarks at http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/annotating/#wmark_text

Answer (score 1):

I did this for about 6000 photos using [FastStone Image Resizer](http://www.faststone.org/FSResizerDownload.htm).  Also lets you save profiles so you can run it again on additional batches.

Answer (score 1):

You can check this online service which may help: http://picghost.com/

Comment: It's a good Site..Thanks for sharing..best thing is batch editing.

Answer (score 0):

http://www.irfanview.com/ is also a great free tool for doing this and more

Just a small selection of features that might be relevant:

> - Batch conversion (with advanced image processing)
> - Scan (batch scan) support
> - Cut/crop
> - **Add overlay text/image (watermark)**
> - IPTC editing
> - Effects (Sharpen, Blur, Adobe 8BF, Filter Factory, Filters Unlimited,    etc.)
> - Screen Capturing
> - Extract icons from EXE/DLL/ICLs
> - Lossless JPG rotation
>
> [image]